# Pandas convert column from str to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For the below dataframe I am using the code

```
df['%'] = ((df['Code Lines'] / df['Code Lines'].sum()) * 100).round(2).astype(str) + '%'
```

output

```
Language    # of Files  Blank Lines Comment Lines   Code Lines  % 
C++              15          66           35            354    6.13%
C/C++ Header      1           3            7              4    0.07%
Markdown          6           73           0            142    2.46%
Python           110         1998       2086           4982    86.27%
Tcl/Tk            1          14           18            273    4.73%
YAML              1           0            6             20    0.35%
```

I am trying to convert the str to float

```
df['%'] = df['% of Total (Code Only)'].astype('float64')
```

Getting error

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py",
>   line 730, in astype_nansafe
>       return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True) ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.35%'

is there a way to maintain the column % as float  along with sign %

Comment: If you keep the `%` sign it will not be float. But it is easy to remove it if you want to do that

Comment: You should just stop with `df['%'] = ((df['Code Lines'] / df['Code Lines'].sum()) * 100).round(2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `str[:-1]` for remove last value (`%`) by [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df['%'] = df['%'].str[:-1].astype('float64')
```

But if possible better is:

```
df['%'] = ((df['Code Lines'] / df['Code Lines'].sum()) * 100).round(2)
```

---

```
print (df)
       Language  # of Files  Blank  Lines Comment  Lines Code Lines      %
0           C++          15     66             35               354   6.13
1  C/C++ Header           1      3              7                 4   0.07
2      Markdown           6     73              0               142   2.46
3        Python         110   1998           2086              4982  86.27
4        Tcl/Tk           1     14             18               273   4.73
5          YAML           1      0              6                20   0.35
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using `strip`:

```
df['%'] = df['%'].str.strip('%').astype('float64')

0     6.13
1     0.07
2     2.46
3    86.27
4     4.73
5     0.35
Name: %, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last character from string as shown below:

`str[:-1]` removes the last character

`df['%'] = df['%'].str[:-1].astype('float64')`

Or you can use replace() to replace `%` with a blank character.

`df['%'] = df['%'].replace("%","").astype('float64')`